VSCODE Debug Blazor API offline? error : Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
How can i debug a Blazor API in vscode when offline?
MSBuild version 17.9.8+b34f75857 for .NET
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.204\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(284,5): warning
NETSDK1206: Found version-specific or distribution-specific runtime identifier(s): win7-x64. Affected librari
es: Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core. In .NET 8.0 and higher, assets for version-specific and distribution-spe
cific runtime identifiers will not be found by default. See https://aka.ms/dotnet/rid-usage for details. [C:\
Users\folder\Desktop\DEV\Azure Static Web Apps\folder\Shared\Shared.csproj]
Shared -> C:\Users\folder\Desktop\DEV\Azure Static Web Apps\folder\Shared\bin\Debug\net8.0\Sh
ared.dll
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.204\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(284,5): warning
NETSDK1206: Found version-specific or distribution-specific runtime identifier(s): win7-x64. Affected librari
es: Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core. In .NET 8.0 and higher, assets for version-specific and distribution-spe
cific runtime identifiers will not be found by default. See https://aka.ms/dotnet/rid-usage for details. [C:\
Users\folder\Desktop\DEV\Azure Static Web Apps\folder\Api\Api.csproj]
Api -> C:\Users\ianco\Desktop\DEV\Azure Static Web Apps\TedcoBlazorApp2024_02\Api\bin\Debug\net8.0\Api.dll
Determining projects to restore...
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.204\NuGet.targets(169,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source
https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. [C:\Users\folder\AppData\Local\Temp\3n3pdx2i.gqf\WorkerExtensions.csproj
]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.204\NuGet.targets(169,5): error :   No such host is known. (api.nuget.org:443
) [C:\Users\folder\AppData\Local\Temp\3n3pdx2i.gqf\WorkerExtensions.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.204\NuGet.targets(169,5): error :   No such host is known. [C:\Users\folder\Ap
pData\Local\Temp\3n3pdx2i.gqf\WorkerExtensions.csproj]

i also tried this ...
dotnet watch run --no-restore
dotnet watch  Hot reload enabled. For a list of supported edits, see https://aka.ms/dotnet/hot-reload.
Press "Ctrl + R" to restart.
dotnet watch  Building...
Determining projects to restore...
All projects are up-to-date for restore.
Shared -> C:\Users\dev\Desktop\DEV\Azure Static Web Apps\folder\Shared\bin\Debug\net8.0\Shared.d
ll

Api -> C:\Users\dev\Desktop\DEV\Azure Static Web Apps\folder\Api\bin\Debug\net8.0\Api.dll
Determining projects to restore...
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.204\NuGet.targets(169,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https
://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.

[C:\Users\dev\AppData\Local\Temp\elqyep1e.0bf\WorkerExtensions.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.204\NuGet.targets(169,5): error :   No such host is known. (api.nuget.org:443) [C:\ 
Users\dev\AppData\Local\Temp\elqyep1e.0bf\WorkerExtensions.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.204\NuGet.targets(169,5): error :   No such host is known. [C:\Users\dev\AppData\ 
Local\Temp\elqyep1e.0bf\WorkerExtensions.csproj]

even func start
results in this error .?
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.204\NuGet.targets(169,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

I found a solution and now I can successfully debug while offline.
Simply add a new file to the root of your project folder:
nuget.config
with this content
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <clear />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>

This will prevent the nuget restore operation that tries to connect to nuget database.
Remember to remove the nuget.config prior to publishing.
